# Javascript - Scopes

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, event-handling

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BigComputer(answer) {
   this.the_answer = answer;
   this.ask_question = function () {
   alert(this.the_answer);
   }
}

 function addhandler() {
   var deep_thought = new BigComputer(42),
   the_button = document.getElementById('thebutton');

   the_button.onclick = deep_thought.ask_question;
}

window.onload = addhandler;
 </script>
```

Why does this script returns undefined instead of 42?
This is how I do understand that:
1) On webpage load we run 'addhandler' method.
2) Inside this method we create instance of BipComputer for deep_thought variable. Also we set up 42 at the answer (public variable inside BipComputer Class)
3) Then we set up reference for the button (inside html file)
4) Button actives on click and here comes the magic:
In my opinion is should print out the number 42, since we just did the set up for this in step 2, but nah the variable is "Undefined"?.

Another question, is what is the difference between running up the method without () (when there are no arguments to pass) and with (). [Like addhandler method].

Maybe this questions are simple, but I used to program in java and php and now the way of thinking in javascript oriented programming is weird for me. Function looks like classes, classes looks like functions, no true constructors and stuff. 
But never mind, lets get back to the questions :) 
I would really appreciate any help.

@Edit

Thanks to @lbstr I found usefull link, for everyone who's asking the same question as I did.
**http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies**

Comment: addhandler is not being explicitly called anywhere in that example. It's being passed as a reference to `window.onload` which the browser calls at the appropriate time. The only time you can execute a function without `()` is when you call it as a constructor.

Comment: @zzzzBov—the function is being added as a click listener for a button, so it's being called by the button's click handler.

Comment: @RobG, let me rephrase that, The only time you can explicitly execute a function without `()` is when you call it as a constructor (i.e. `new Foo`). Any other case requires invoking a browser function or behavior to call the function for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when the click handler is fired, `this` is the button. Here's what you want to do:

```
function BigComputer(answer) {
    this.the_answer = answer;
    var self = this;
    this.ask_question = function() {
        alert(self.the_answer);
    };
}
```

This is all made possible by the wonderfulness of closures. Many js fans agree that this is the best part of the language. [Read all about 'em](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+closures).

It is important to distinguish scope from `this`. Although variables are scoped by functions, `this` is not necessarily the same in a given scope chain. A simple example is the fact that I can invoke any function I want with whatever value of `this` that I want:

```
someFunc.call(someThis); // call someFunc, using someThis for this
```

For event handlers, `this` is commonly the element on which the event originated. That is nice, because you might have several buttons on the page and you want to do something to the one that was clicked.

Comment: So I need to use "var self = this", whenever I work with DOM elements? Shouldn't this work as scope for object inside which it was created?

Comment: @Dariss great question -- see my edit above, which will hopefully answer it.

Comment: @Dariss—a function's *this* is set by how the function is called (or by [*bind*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)). So if you don't set the right *this* in the call you can't fix it later. Keeping a reference to the instance in a closure makes it available again, though it's not a particularly efficient method. Better to work out another scheme.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that after you assign

```
the_button.onclick = deep_thought.ask_question;
```

when the button is clicked, the function assigned to the `onclick` property is called with `this` bound to the button. You can address the problem in (at least) three ways:

- by rewriting the function (as in [the answer by lbstr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19392082/535871))
- by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function that executes `ask_question` with the desired `this`:

  ```
  the_button.onclick = deep_thought.ask_question.bind(deep_thought);
  ```

  Note that `bind` is new to JS 1.8.5; the link above has a shim for older JS engines.
- by writing a closure to get the correct `this` inside `ask_question`:

  ```
  the_button.onclick = function() { deep_thought.ask_question(); };
  ```

  EDIT: As RobG points out in a comment, this code creates a memory leak in some browsers (notably many versions of MSIE). A fix would be to eliminate the variable `the_button` completely:

  ```
  document.getElementById('thebutton').onclick = function() {
      deep_thought.ask_question();
  };
  ```

  See [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks) for other approaches.

Comment: The last suggestion does create a closure, but that's not why it works. It just sets *this* to the right value in the call. The closures are unused (and unwanted since they can cause memory issues in some browsers in this case). The next line should be `the_button = null` to remove the most problematic circular reference caused by closures.

Comment: @RobG - The closure captures the value of the local variable `deep_thought`, which is key to calling `ask_question` in such a way that `this` is set to the right value. I'm not sure what you mean by "that's not why it works".

Comment: @TedHopp—I was just trying to highlight that it it sets *this* to the right value because of how the function is called, not because a closure is involved. Good to see an alternative avoiding the circular reference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the ask_question() to be executed from button click, "this" would be the context of the button not the this of constructor based deep_thought variable. If you remove the "this" from this.the_answer and make it just var, you will get alert of 42.